# Using external database for user logins in Django

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I have a Django application where, in development, I was using the default database (sqlite3, I believe) to store user login info. I had a line in my Dockerfile (which would spin up my app) that would add a user and it would automatically just be stored in the default database.

Now that it's moving to production, it would be a colossal pain to add each user one at a time every time we need to update. From what I read in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/), it looked like I just needed to modify my `settings.py` from

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

to

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'name_of_user_table',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password'

    }
}
```

I don't use the login info anywhere else in my code, and I can't find any reference to the database aside from in `settings.py`. Have I done enough to ensure that it can be connected to the external postgreSQL database of user logins, or is there more I need to do? This is my first Django application and I'm still learning how all of this stuff works.

Comment: the `settings.py` is where we define the `db` type that will be used in `django`. I am a little confused. Are you looking for DB migration to be handled by django ?

Comment: @error404 not quite--just need to use an external database for user login info. It's currently set up in my Dockerfile where I set environment variables for a username, an email, and a password and use that to login. The Dockerfile also runs python manage.py migrate.

Comment: I'm also confused. Are you getting mixed up between the credentials for the database, and the logins themselves?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry for the confusion. Instead of creating a user every time I run my Dockerfile, I want it to use the usernames and passwords contained in an external database.

Comment: yes...by updating the settings.py you can point to an external `db`

Comment: @error404 but am I ok since I just put in place of the default and left the name the same? or is there any reason to suspect it will be an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there will be any issue.

The below is the configuration I have been using for a while with postgres.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'test_db',
        'USER': 'test',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin@123',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Also if the db is completely new you will need to perform migrations i.e. apply migrations.

Hope so the above helps